# Assigning values to names in excel in order to do operations

Tags: microsoft-excel

Lets say generally I would like a table with 3 columns:

[image: Table]

I would like to be able to reference the name of the column 'Name' have some function input and some function output. In this simple example the output is just multiplied by 2.

I would like to have a function that either takes a number or the name(s) of a series and would allow for trivial operations such as a+b, a * b, etc.

How would I write such a function? It seems to me easy to do a simple VLOOKUP (triggered by if the cell begins with a letter rather than a number) in the case of a single series e.g. if I wanted to reference simply "a" again. But what if I wanted to input a + b for instance?

Comment: a+b=6.5 or 13??? Is it possible to have a+b+c?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I fully understand your question, but the example below might provide some ideas. I used two VLOOKUPS to handle the two values in your formula along with LEFT and RIGHT to put these values in the VLOOKUP. Of course this assumes the layout of the formula does not change.

[image]